# Case when in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to write a query in which I have to perform a selection in a where clause according to a defined variable.

My script looks like this:

```
def schd_yn ='Y';
def clin_schd = '1,2';

CREATE TABLE TEMP_SUBOPT AS 
  SELECT *
    FROM P112921.SCHEDULE_DATA     
    WHERE clin_sch IN (CASE WHEN '&schd_yn.' = 'Y' 
                            THEN &clin_schd.
                            ELSE clin_sch
                         END)
;
```

What I would like to do exactly is take all data from my source in case the schd_yn is set to N, and to take only the values defined in clin_schd in case schd_yn is set to Y.

This solution works well in the case you only have 1 value in clin_sched.

These combinations works well:

```
def schd_yn='Y'; //takes only clin_sch=1
def clin_schd='1';

def schd_yn='N'; //takes everything as expected
def clin_schd='1';
```

These combinations doesn't work properly and generates errors:

```
def schd_yn='Y';
def clin_schd='1,2';

def schd_yn='N';
def clin_schd='1,2';
```

Does someone knows how to make this work?

Thank you

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Don't use comma separated values in SQL. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You shouldn't have removed to sqldeveloper tag, because this script seems SQL Developer specific. I've added the tag again.

Comment: Does dynamic SQL in SQL Developer work this way? Variables get inserted as substrings into the SQL string?

Comment: So what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
select ...
from
your_table
where
def schd_yn='Y' and def clin_schd='1'
union all
select ...
from
your_table
where
def schd_yn='N' and def clin_schd='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this logic:

```
WHERE (&schd_yn = 'N' OR clin_sch = &clin_schd)
```

You are asking for:

> What I would like to do exactly is take all data from my source in
>   case the schd_yn is set to N, and to take only the values defined in
>   clin_schd in case schd_yn is set to Y.

The above works if `schd_yn` can only be `'N'` or `'Y'` (a reasonable assumption, in my opinion).  More formally, you seem to want:

```
WHERE (&schd_yn = 'N' OR (&schd_yn = 'Y' AND clin_sch = &clin_schd))
```

Comment: I think it would be quite the logic I want, however, if my schd_yn='N', it would make sense to leave clin_schd=''
And this, however, doesn't work